# Electron : App minimize or not visible after click outside browserWindow or Windows key+D

Tags: node.js, electron

I am developing a desktop widget which shows current system status. But the problem is when any user clicks outside of browser window the app get hide/not visible on the desktop. The same thing happens when user press key windows key +D. Is there anything that we can do for preventing this or catch this event and call window.show(). Because lots of desktop widget support this kind of feature.

Edit: I have tried `alwaysOnTop` property of browserWindow, but I don't want to show my app above the other apps. Like any desktop widget which always shows on the desktop.

Comment: Hmm, there are minimize and hide events on the BrowserWindow, not sure if this is what you want though

Comment: @Rhayene These events dose does not catch click event outside browser and windows key + D as well.

Comment: aww thats a shame :( maybe you could hack something with the [global keyboard-shortcuts](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/keyboard-shortcuts.md)

Comment: Thank you @Rhayene, I think this can help.

Comment: @Rhayene: No it doesn't work 

globalShortcut.register('Super+d', () => {
      window.show();
      console.log('Super+d is pressed')
    })

I think Super+d is already registered with windows so it is not working. I have also tried on menu


label: ' UnHide',
         accelerator: 'Super+d',
         click: function () {
          window.show();
           console.log('Super+d is pressed')
         }

Not working there as well.Is there any eventListener for Super+D?

Comment: @Rhayene: Update : globalShortcut.isRegistered('Super+d') returns -> false; So, "Super+d" is not registered. Still it is not catching any event on these key press.